# How to select TextNodes matching a certain regex in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have HTML and want to find TextNodes matching a certain regexp. I see in the API that I can find Elements but I need TextNodes.

Comment: Maybe an empty `contains()` is able to select all text elements? Or just use `:matches(),`, it seems to test text only, see [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). You may also see how it can be done with jQuery, since jsoup has jQuery-like methods, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html):

> - **`:matches(regex)`**
>
>   Elements **whose text matches** the specified regular
>     expression. The text may appear in the found element, or any of its
>     descendants.
>
>   Examples:
>     `td:matches(\\d+)` finds table cells containing digits.
>     `div:matches((?i)login)` finds divs containing the text, case
>     insensitively.
> - **`:containsOwn(text)`**
>
>   Elements that **directly contain the specified text**.
>     The search is case insensitive. The text must appear in the found
>     element, not any of its descendants.
>
>   Example:
>     `p:containsOwn(jsoup)` finds p
>     elements with own text "jsoup".
> - **`:matchesOwn(regex)`**
>
>   Elements whose own **text matches the specified
>     regular expression**. The text must appear in the found element, not any
>     of its descendants.
>
>   Examples:
>     `td:matchesOwn(\\d+)` finds table cells directly
>     containing digits.
>     `div:matchesOwn((?i)login)` finds divs containing the
>     text, case insensitively.