# how to extract email id using jsoup?

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

```
Elements elements = doc.select("span.st"); 
for (Element e : elements) {        
out.println("<p>Text : " + e.text()+"</p>");
}
```

Element `e` contains text with some email id in it. How to extract the `maild` id from it. I have seen the Jsoup API doc which provides `:matches(regex)`, but I didn't understand how to use it. I'm trying to use

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&’*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$

which I found while googling.

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:matches(regex)` is useful if you want to find something based on a specified regex (e.g. find all nodes that contain email).

I think this is not what you want. [Instead, you need to extract the email from `e.text()` using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703751/819651). In your case:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("span.st"); 
for (Element e : elements) {        
    out.println("<p>Text : " + e.text()+"</p>");
    out.println(extractEmail(e.text()));
}

// ...
public static String extractEmail(String str) {
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-    9-.]+").matcher(str);
   while (m.find()) {
       return m.group();
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you @Luís Soares. i'm able to get the email with your solution but i don't understand the usage of :matches(regex). I tried jsoup api but i didn't get it. if possible give me an example.  Thank you

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23319612/819651
I don't have and haven't found any example but the process would be like:
`doc.select("span.st:matches(@)")` would impose a stricter condition in your example; it would only select the nodes containing `@` inside (regardless of the level of nesting).